# how to connect to different databases for each session

Tags: connection, entitymanager

I have a Web Application (Netbeans 7.2, Glassfish 3.1, PostgreSQL 9.1) where each my customer has it's own database (all databases are identical in structure).

I need that at login the application change the database connection (and entityManager) to the relevant one for the customer.

The initial (default) connection parameters are defined in "glassfish-resources.xml" and the associations Customer-DatabaseName are defined in a text file (all databases resides in the same server).

How I can manage a different connection for each customer?
How I can close the default entityManager and create a new with a new db connection?

Thank you very much.